# SQL Event - DELETE AND UPDATE rows on tables after UPDATE other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to have a tricky SQL statement as an Event that runs every couple of minutes.

Currently, I'm doing so with Java, using 3 separate statements that executing sequentiality in a transaction connection.

Q: I don't know how to construct such an SQL statement without Java. If impossible to have a single SQL statement, I'd like to use transaction (as I'm using in Java) and rollback in case of failure in any of those separate statements.

**My Case:**
I have 3 tables: "`Factory`", "`Plan`", "`Machine`".
I want to do something as below:

```
1.
WHERE Machines.annualCheck == "TRUE"
SET Machine.status = "IN_ANNUAL_CHECK"

For machines that got updated I need to do the following:

2.1 Update the related factory
WHERE Factory.id == Machine.linkFactoryID
UPDATE Factory.totalActiveMachines = --1

2.2 Delete the upcoming plans that planned to be handled by the related machine
DELETE rows WHERE Plan.willHandleByMachineID = Machine.ID
```

p.s. I'm using MySQL

**Thank you!**

---

**Update:**

In following to Simonare suggestion, I tired to do the following:

```
DELIMITER $

CREATE PROCEDURE annualCheck(IN Machine_ID int, IN Factory_ID int)
BEGIN
  UPDATE machine_table 
  SET machine_table.annualCheck = 'IN_ANNUAL_CHECK'
  WHERE machine_table.machine_id = Machine_ID;

  UPDATE factory_table
  SET factory_table.totalActiveMachines = factory_table.totalActiveMachines - 1
  WHERE factory_table.factory_id = Factory_ID;

  DELETE FROM plan_table WHERE plan_table.assign_to_machine = Machine_ID
END$

DELIMITER $$

BEGIN
    SELECT @m_id = machine_id, @f_id = link_factory_id
    FROM machine_table
    WHERE machine_table.annualCheck = 'TRUE';
END$$

CALL annualCheck(@m_id,@f_id)
```

I don't know why, but I'm running into syntax errors - one after the other.
It's my first time to use PROCEDURE and DELIMITER. Am I doing it right?

Comment: there are few things you can take a look for 1. `Triggers in mysql` & 2. `On DELETE CASCADE` I think these terms may help you.

Comment: Hoe many records does your last select query expected to return?

Comment: Simonare, let's say around 100.

Comment: Thank you Kaushik. I'll take a look.

Comment: on the first block, you have missing semicolon on DELETE statement. on the second block, you have not declared @m_id, @f_id. ex: `DECLARE @m_id INT;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use stored procedure

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE myProc (IN Machine_ID int)
BEGIN
  UPDATE myTable 
  SET Machine.status = "IN_ANNUAL_CHECK"
  WHERE Machines.annualCheck == "TRUE";

  Update the related factory
  WHERE Factory.id == Machine.linkFactoryID
  UPDATE Factory.totalActiveMachines =  totalActiveMachines  -1;

  DELETE FROM Plan WHERE Plan.willHandleByMachineID = Machine_ID;
END//
```

then you can execute it either from mysql

```
 CALL simpleproc(@a);
```

or from Java

Comment: Thank you very much. I never used `PROCEDURE` before. could you please take a look at my last update, and tell me if you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: looking forward to hearing back from you

Comment: If this answer is helpful for you, please consider to upvote :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to create trigger on the Machine table, something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `TRG_Machines_AfterUpdate` AFTER UPDATE ON `Machine` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF OLD.annualCheck = 'TRUE' AND NEW.annualCheck = 'IN_ANNUAL_CHECK' THEN
        UPDATE
            Factory
        SET
            totalActiveMachines = totalActiveMachines - 1
        WHERE
            id = NEW.linkFactoryID
        ;

        DELETE FROM
            Plan
        WHERE
            willHandleByMachineID = NEW.ID
        ;
    END;
END
```

So you can just issue normal update:

`UPDATE Machine SET annualCheck = 'IN_ANNUAL_CHECK' WHERE annualCheck = 'TRUE'`